# Why use %files directive in RPM spec file and how to automate file listing in that section?

Tags: rpmbuild

Why does `%files` needed and why it cannot be created automatically by listing `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` directory contents?
For example, in that spec file i have to use some modifications in it in script, that build an RPM package for me. I have to `cd` into `~/RPM/SOURCES`, then `find .` in it and `echo` each line into `.spec` file to setup `%files` section. It can be done automatically by the tool using the same techniuque i do in the background but from `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` directory instead?

```
%install
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/MyCompany/MyProduct/
cp -rf -- ~/RPM/SOURCES/* $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/MyCompany/MyProduct/

%files
/opt/MyCompany/MyProduct/file_1
/opt/MyCompany/MyProduct/file_2
/opt/MyCompany/MyProduct/file_3
... - a lot of lines here
/opt/MyCompany/MyProduct/file_100000
```

**UPD**:
Yes it is possible to use all copied files automatically (Doc http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html)
In my case `%files` can be rewritten as that

```
%files
/opt/MyCompany/MyProduct/*
```

It will take files from `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/MyCompany/MyProduct`, so to use star we need to omit build root which is `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` or `%{buildroot}` (Which is default path where rpm searches for files IIUC)

Comment: I donʼt know which were strongest design decisions or historical order, but here are some potential reasons: split packages where different packages would have different `%files` directives, using `%doc` etc. to change how files are handled, somewhere to put `%ghost` files, temporary build files from poorly-behaving install scripts, etc.

Comment: @DanielH so you mean there is no way to automate it?

Comment: Especially because of the last point about poorly-behaved install scripts, you probably don’t actually *want* to without at least checking, and you can’t *fully* automate it if you have docs, config files, or ghost files, or if you need to change attributes, etc.  But I think there’s some way to use wildcards so you don’t need to fully list everything if you’re sure you don’t want to.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does %files needed and why it cannot be created automatically by listing
> $RPM_BUILD_ROOT directory contents?

It is common that one spec file build creates multiple (sub)packages - then also
[multiple %files sections are needed](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-subpack-spec-file-changes.html).

Even though there exist *some* automatic %files
[section](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/scl-utils/blob/38bf7c968affe9a3bd6ad527f20112ec906d7232/f/macros.scl-filesystem#_1-97)
[generators](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/blob/master/scripts/find-debuginfo.sh),
nb there's the
[%files -f option](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s05s06.html),
in general it isn't possible to split the files automatically.

Worth saying that most of the package maintainers don't maintain the software
source code, but just package the "upstream" releases.  If the %files sections
are rather manually maintained (in contrast with the wildcard patterns), the
package maintainer has everything a bit more under control because he is
notified about the changes in the software installation layout (e.g. when a new
file appears in `/usr/bin` with a new release, rpmbuild starts complaining that
there's a new "unpackaged" file, see below).

> It can be done automatically by the tool using the same techniuque i do in the
> background but from $RPM_BUILD_ROOT directory instead?

You don't even have to run `find` manually.  As long as %install creates the
files in $RPM_BUILD_ROOT, if you don't mention them in %files - you get reports
like those:

```
$ rpmbuild -bb *.spec
...
Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /home/user/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/test-1-1.x86_64
error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
   /usr/bin/not-packaged

RPM build errors:
    Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
   /usr/bin/not-packaged
```